# If a set $A$ is uncountable , and a set $B$ is countable then $A \times B$ is uncountable.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, cardinals

I prove it by contradiction.
Let $A \times B$ is countable. It means we can list down the all the ordered pairs of $A \times B$.
So if ordered pairs of the form $(a,b)$ are countable (where $a \in A$ and $b \in B$ ), it implies $A$ and $B$ are countable.
But here lies a contradiction since $A$ is uncountable. So our supposition is wrong and $A \times B$ is uncountable.

Is my reasoning alright? What can be a better way to prove this ?

Comment: A countable set cannot have an uncountable subset.

Comment: Id argue like this. In particular there is SOME element in $B$. What can you say about $A\times\{b\}$?

Comment: Counterexample: If $B$ is the empty set, then $A \times B$ is also the empty set, which is actually countable.

Comment: What @McFry said. The result is true if $B$ is countable *and nonempty*. And then, ... what Zachary said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your argument isn’t really complete: you *say* that countability of $A\times B$ implies countability of $A$ and of $B$, but you don’t actually justify this.

In any case you’re working much too hard. Fix $b\in B$, and define

$$f:A\to A\times B:a\mapsto\langle a,b\rangle\;;$$

it’s very easy to verify that $f$ is injective and hence that $|A|\le|A\times B|$. (Note that this argument does require that $B$ be non-empty; this is crucial, since $A\times\varnothing=\varnothing$ is actually countable.)

Comment: Can you tell how the injection is proved from A to A X B?

Comment: @Huma: There’s almost no work to be done: if $f(a_0)=f(a_1)$, then $\langle a_0,b\rangle=\langle a_1,b\rangle$, and therefore (by the definition of ordered pair) $a_0=a_1$.